# AuthorizationFilterAttribute OnAuthorization method is not firing in Sitecore 10

Tags: pipelines, authentication

Authorization filter attribute is not firing

```
 public class AuthenticationRequiredAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        public override bool AllowMultiple
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
        
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {            
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
           
        }
```

I have decorated controller with the attribute

```
 [AuthenticationRequired]
    public class ProfileController : BaseController
    {        
        public ProfileController(IMyRepository repository)
            : base(repository)
        {
        }
    }
```

the  *AuthenticationRequired* filter is not firing

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add an `Initialize` pipeline processor to add the new filter.

```
<initialize>
  <processor type="InitializeNamespace.InitializeClassName, LibraryName" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeGlobalFilters, Sitecore.Mvc']" resolve="true">
  </processor>
</initialize>
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using Sitecore.Pipelines;

namespace InitializeNamespace
{
    public class InitializeClassName
    {       
        public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new AuthenticationRequiredAttribute());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not work. code is still not getting executed

Answer (score 0):

Try inheriting your class from `FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter`.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
public class AuthenticationRequiredAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        //your custom logic goes here.
    }
}
```

Decorate your controller with attributes.

```
[AuthenticationRequired]
public class ProfileController : Controller
{        
   public ProfileController(IMyRepository repository) : base(repository)
   {
   }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a Web API filter instead of an MVC filter.
Inherit your custom authorization filter from  `System.Web.Mvc.FilterAttribute` class and `System.Web.Mvc.IAuthorizationFilter` interface, and implement `OnAuthorization()` method.

For example,

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Sitecore;


namespace {YOUR_PROJECT_NAMESPACE}
{
    public class AuthenticationRequired : System.Web.Mvc.FilterAttribute, System.Web.Mvc.IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            {YOUR_CUSTOM_CODE_LOGIC}
        }
    }

}
```

You can configure your custom filter in your application at three levels:

- **Global level** by registering your filter in `Application_Start` event of `Global.asax.cs`;
- **Controller level** by decorating a controller with your filter by putting your filter at the top of the controller name;
- **Action level** by decorating a given action method with your filter in a similar way as above for controllers.

In your case you simply need to decorate your controller with your custom filter.

Hope this helps.